# How to requiere a js file in Fiddle.js

Tags: vue.js, jsfiddle

I'm trying to make a fiddlejs.

The Code use a VueJS plugin called VueDragula, inside the code, I have:

```
let VueDragula = require('../vue-dragula');
Vue.use(VueDragula);
```

So, I uploaded vue-dragula.js to my own server, and added it to external resources, and delete the 2 lines, but now, it says

> VueDragula is not defined

I also tried to include directly the content of vue-dragula inside the JS, but happened the same thing.

How should I do that???

Comment: Can you link the fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xoco70/vzk27smw/9/ I have included it via external ressource and remove the 2 lines, it works, but now, I can't call Vue.VueDragula... events in fiddle